# extending all subclasses of superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, dry

I have a one to many class inheritance structure as follows:

```
class SuperClass:
  def func1():
    print 'hello'

  def func2():
    print 'ow'

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
   def func1():
     print 'hi'

class SubClass2(SuperClass):
   def func1():
     print 'howdy'

...
```

I want to add functionality to class A so that I can use it when I create classes B and C (etc), but I cannot edit the code for class A directly. My current solution is:

```
def func3():
  print 'yes!'

SuperClass.func3 = func3
```

Is there a better and/or more pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: Why does the functionality have to be added to class `A`? Can't it just be a plain old function in some other namespace? "Hammering *everything* into classes" certainly isn't pythonic.

Comment: Yes please explain your use case

Comment: Also, if you are implementing B and C, you could add an intermediat type that extends the superclass with the desired functionality, and make B and C extend that class instead

Comment: @millimoose Yes the example certainly glossed over many possibly pertinent details. `func3` acts directly and only on things that `SuperClass` owns. It's functionality that 'should have been' included in SuperClass but wasn't. I can update the example if that's not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "monkeypatching", and is perfectly reasonable in some cases.

For example if you have to use someone else's code (that you can't modify) that depends on `SuperClass`, and you need to change that code's behavior, your only real choice is to replace methods on `SuperClass`.

---

However, in your case, there doesn't seem to be any good reason to do this. You're defining all of the subclasses of `SuperClass`, so why not just add another class in between?

```
class Intermediate(SuperClass):
    def func3():
        pass

class SubClass1(Intermediate):
    def func1():
        print 'hi'
```

This isn't good enough for "functionality that should have been in `SuperClass` but wasn't" if other code you can't control needs that functionality… but when it's only *your code* that needs that functionality, it's just as good, and a lot simpler.

---

If even the subclasses aren't under your control, often you can just derive a new class from each one that *is*. For example:

```
class Func3Mixin(object):
    def func3():
        pass

class F3SubClass1(SubClass1, Func3Mixin):
    pass

class F3SubClass2(SubClass2, Func3Mixin):
    pass
```

Now you just construct instances of `F3SubClass1` instead of `SubClass1`. Code that was expecting a `SubClass1` instance can use an `F3SubClass1` just fine. And Python's duck typing makes this kind of "mixin-oriented programming" especially simple: inside the implementation of `Func3Mixin.func3`, you can use attributes and methods of `SuperClass`, despite the fact that `Func3Mixin` itself isn't statically related to `SuperClass` in any way, because you know that any runtime object that is a `Func3Mixin` will also be a `SuperClass`.

---

Meanwhile, even when monkeypatching *is* appropriate, it isn't necessarily the best answer. For example, if you're patching to work around a bug in some third-party code, that code has a nice license and a source repository that makes it easy to maintain your own patches, you can just fork it, create a fixed copy, and use that instead of the original.

---

Also, it's worth pointing out that none of your classes are actually usable as written—any attempt to call any of the methods will raise a `TypeError` because they're missing the `self` argument. But the way you've monkeypatched in `func3`, it will fail in exactly the same way as `func1`. (And the same is true for the alternatives I sketched above.)

---

Finally, all of your classes here are classic classes rather than new-style, because you forgot to make `SuperClass` inherit from `object`. If you can't change `SuperClass`, of course, that's not your fault—but you may want to fix it anyway by making your subclasses (or `Intermediate`) multiply inherit from `object` and `SuperClass`. (If you've been paying attention: yes, this means you can mix-in new-style-classness. Although under the covers you have to understand metaclasses to understand why.)

Comment: Appreciate your comments. By the way I don't have control over the `SubClass`es either. I want to add functionality to `SuperClass` so that an object of  `SubClass1`, or `SubClass2` or any other sub class would be able to use that code.

Comment: Can you create your own subclasses of each subclass? (I don't want this to sound _too_ negative. You should avoid monkeypatching when it's reasonably possible to avoid… but in any case where the alternatives are clumsy, or even hackier, etc., definitely use it.)

Comment: "Monkeypatching" also has the more respectable name of "Aspect Oriented Programming".

Comment: @Apalala: Well, they're not quite the same thing (except to opponents of AOP). AOP is about designing things to be patched (and patched together). Monkeypatching is about doing that to objects that _weren't_ designed to be patched. Alternatively: AOP is what you do when you recognize that one of your abstractions is crosscutting; monkeypatching is what you do when you're stuck using a library built by someone who failed to recognize that.

Comment: @abarnert The typical example of AOP is adding logging to methods that didn't have it. But this is not worth discussing that. In Python, we call it "monkeypatching", and, despite the name, we consider it a valid technique.